# Migrating a Wordpress website from cloud9 to our own server

Tags: wordpress

I had designed a WordPress website in cloud9 but now I wanted it to migrate to my server (company server) can anyone help me with this?

Comment: That's not how this site works. Have a read of this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

These quite a few migration tutorials on the internet. But if you're unsure, I would ask a professional to help. You need to change the table values in the post content and url section of the database as well as the images. It's quite a task.

This is from the Codex:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_to_a_New_Server

Check it out, have a read and do some more research. But again I'd recommend hiring a WordPress LAMP dev - they'd be able to migrate in about a few hours - the thing which takes the longest is the DNS switchover.

Comment: This should be a comment at best.

Comment: Accidentally pressing enter and editing whilst you commented. Sozzz